# Annotations not firing in SharedDriver with cucumber-jvm

Tags: java, selenium, annotations, webdriver, cucumber-jvm

This is driving me nuts.  I'm running a test framework using cucumber-jvm and trying to get it to take screenshots.
I have looked at the java-webbit-websockets-selenium example that's provided and have implemented the same method of calling my webdriver using the SharedDriver module.
For some reason, my @Before and @After methods are not being called (I've put print statements in there).  Can anyone shed any light?

SharedDriver:

```
package com.connectors;

import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class SharedDriver extends EventFiringWebDriver {




    private static final WebDriver REAL_DRIVER = new FirefoxDriver();

        private static final Thread CLOSE_THREAD = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                REAL_DRIVER.close();
            }
        };

        static {
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(CLOSE_THREAD);
        }

        public SharedDriver() {
            super(REAL_DRIVER);
            REAL_DRIVER.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            REAL_DRIVER.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1200,800));
            System.err.println("DRIVER");
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            if(Thread.currentThread() != CLOSE_THREAD) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You shouldn't close this WebDriver. It's shared and will close when the JVM exits.");
            }
            super.close();
        }

        @Before()
        public void deleteAllCookies() {
            manage().deleteAllCookies();
            System.err.println("BEFORE");
        }

        @After
        public void embedScreenshot(Scenario scenario) {
            System.err.println("AFTER");
            try {
                byte[] screenshot = getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
                scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
            } catch (WebDriverException somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots) {
                System.err.println(somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots.getMessage());
            }
        }


    }
```

Step file:

```
package com.tests;

import com.connectors.BrowserDriverHelper;
import com.connectors.SharedDriver;
import com.connectors.FunctionLibrary;

import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import cucumber.runtime.PendingException;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;


import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: stuartalexander
 * Date: 23/11/12
 * Time: 15:18
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class addComponentsST {
    String reportName;
    String baseUrl = BrowserDriverHelper.getBaseUrl();
    private final WebDriver driver;

    public addComponentsST(SharedDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Given("^I have navigated to the \"([^\"]*)\" of a \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void I_have_navigated_to_the_of_a(String arg1, String arg2) throws Throwable {
        // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
        assertEquals(1,2);
        throw new PendingException();
    }
```

CukeRunner:

```
package com.tests;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(tags = {"@wip"}, format = { "pretty","html:target/cucumber","json:c:/program files (x86)/jenkins/jobs/cucumber tests/workspace/target/cucumber.json" }, features = "src/resources/com/features")
public class RunCukesIT {
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `SharedDriver` in the same package as `RunCukesIT`, i.e. `com.tests`.

When using the JUnit runner, the glue becomes the unit test package (here `com.tests`), and this is where cucumber-jvm will “scan” the classes for annotations.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I've been bashing my head against this issue for ages :)

Comment: I was unfortunate enough to have to figure this out the hard way and stumble across your answer later. +1 Though.

Comment: Hi Guys. Let me ask a question regarding this. Where do I need to instantiate the webdriver if I have multiple steps files and multiple page object for each page on the site. Right now, every page object class extends the BasePage.class which contains all the instantiation for the framework. But I'm confused in case of shared driver how can I handle it! Thank you!